# Django url conf understanding the syntax

Tags: python, regex, django

I've been reading the `django` docs but this is still unclear. I have this piece of url code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/), I know `r` means raw string, but what is this:

```
'^$'
```

What does the `^` mean, what does the `$` mean? There is no clear explanation on the docs?

Comment: From web below: URL patterns (simple regular expressions)
read more: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/ 
^-begin
$-end

Comment: Regular expressions are a Python feature. The full documentation about regular expressions is available [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

These are regular expressions.

`^` indicates the start of a regular expression.

`$` indicates the end of a regular expression.

You can look at [some examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#example) from the docs.